# I would like to add various custom tabs to a range of products is it possible to have different tabs for each product?

Tags: custom, tabs

Hi I have many products which I would require extra tabs for. I would like to be able to arrange the order of the tabs and also have different tabs for various products. I don't want the tabs to be the same on every product page is this possible?

I've see some extensions for custom tabs but without downloading these and installing them I've no idea if any of them would be suitable.

Comment: if you use custom static blocks for individual products, will it not work ?

Comment: Thanks Naveed for your reply. I'm really new to Magento so I've no idea if that would work. I've added some products to the new website I'm having done, on the actual product page you get tabs like details, more information and reviews. I really need a lot more tabs than these, so I was looking for an easy way to add more.